# Insert/Update records in hive table based on 3 scenarios in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have one source table and i want to update/insert data's into output tables based on below scenarios.

Source table :

```
Name|age|dept|sal |school|college|deg|blood_group
aaa |10 |ece |1000|svv   |sas    |be |0+
bbb |20 |it  |2000|svv   |sas    |be |A+



scenario 1: If value name,age,dept doesn't exists on output table,create new record
scenario 2: If value name,age,dept exists on output table , if no changes in school,college then do nothing
scenario 3: If value name,age,dept exists on output table , if changes in school,college then do nothing then create new record



I want to insert data's into output table based on above scenario using either spark sql or spark scala dataframe.

Please suggest me.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not super sure if this will work or not

1. Try To Call the Hive Table in your code first before writing , and create a Table /Dataframe out of it and call it prior_df

   ```
   from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
        hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
        bank = hive_context.table("default.bank")
        bank.show()
   ```

> ```
> bank.registerTempTable("bank_temp")
> hive_context.sql("select * from bank_temp").show()
> ```

2. Now, join with the prior_df table and as you have already have an condition using withColumn and when condition create a new column for "No Action/Filter" transactions likewise. The prior_df will help you get the previous value
3. Write the new DF to the hive table location